# Python 3 assigning 2 values to a variable

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

```
import subprocess
import time

Python = True

firefoxbrowser = 'firefox', 'firefox browser'

FirefoxLink = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'

while Python is True:
    print("What program do you want to open?")
    program = ''
    launch = ''
    program = input().lower()

    if program = firefoxbrowser:
        launch = FirefoxLink #launch will be used for later commands
        print("launching Firefox!")

    #reserved for later work
```

I'm trying to make a program to launch Firefox when I type OR firefox browser OR firefox in the command line.
I want to assign 2 values to firefoxbrowser, for both 'firefox' and 'firefox browser'. Yet, using " 'firefox', 'firefox browser' " or using " 'firefox' and 'firefox browser' " breaks the program in multiple ways.
How can I achieve 2 values for one variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to change

```
if program = firefoxbrowser:
```

to

```
if program in firefoxbrowser:
```

`firefoxbrowser` is a tuple.  Check if `program` is one of its elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a tuple like this:

```
firefox_browser = ("firefox", "firefox browser")
```

You then should be able to access it like this with indexing:

```
firefox_browser[0]
firefox_browser[1]
```

You can also access the items through tuple unpacking:

```
ffb1, ffb2 = firefox_browser
```

Comment: The original code already creates a tuple, it's the comma that matters for creating a tuple, not the parentheses. Including the parens is a bit nicer style wise though

Comment: @Marius Well, the user mentioned that it "broke the program", so I figured that including the parentheses might fix it, but yeah, it should work fine without them.